# Python dictionary is empty while imported to another module

Tags: python, dictionary, python-module

This is a project template so I can't change much...

I will omit what I believe are irrelevant parts:

```
#file server.py
import functions
import json
import socket

funcs = {}


class JSONRPCServer:
    """The JSON-RPC server."""

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = None

    def register(self, name, function):
        """Registers a function."""
        funcs[name] = function
(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test the JSONRPCServer class
    server = JSONRPCServer('0.0.0.0', 8000)

    # Register functions
    server.register('hello', functions.hello)
    server.register('greet', functions.greet)
    server.register('add', functions.add)
    server.register('sub', functions.sub)
    server.register('mul', functions.mul)
    server.register('div', functions.div)

    print(funcs)

    # Start the server
    server.start()
```

Here this will print all my functions inside the funcs dict.

I have another file that needs the contents of funcs but for testing I have this:

```
#file test.py

from server import funcs

print(funcs)
```

This prints an empty dictionary. How do I make it so that funcs keeps it's values across these two files?

Comment: The main of the the first file is ran is you do `python server.py` but not if you just import, so funcs is never filled

Comment: I always need to have server.py running before anything else. funcs is populated and printed well and if i then run tests.py funcs will be empty there

Comment: If you run the server in a terminal, that fills func in this process, if you import from another run you won't have it

Comment: can't I send funcs content to another module then? Or can I make the new module ask for it?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the test.py file, anything within the

```
if __name__ == "__main__"
```

of the server.py isn't being run, since it isn't the main file (when you run server.py directly, it IS going into the `if __main__` and therefore filling up the funcs dict). Therefore, all those `server.register` calls aren't being run when you run the `test.py` file, and hence your `funcs` dict is empty.

Maybe put that piece of code with all the register calls in a different function, and call that directly?

Comment: Yes. Or just remove the `if` and let the main prog `import server`

Comment: The principle here and I cannot change that is that server.py will be running.
A client.py will connect and do stuff like invoking those functions. All that works because the server knows whats inside funcs and can call them. But I need to have a third module that keeps track of the functions the server register. And this module that i call tests.py here must at all times if called give back the funcs values.

Comment: You're saying that server.py is ALWAYS running, and you need to be able to call another script to know what `funcs` value is?

Comment: If so, it's a bit of an issue- basically you have two python processes, and one needs to access a dictionary from the other. You're definitely going to need to change something in the server.py script so that you'll be able to do this (it's pretty shitty looking through the memory of another process).
I'd suggest dumping `funcs` to a json (or maybe pickle) that test.py will read- if this sounds good, I can explain more

Comment: yes... server.py is running all the time waiting for client requests, all that works as intended. This tests.py module must run and get all functions that the server currently knows (not just the names but the function object as well)

Comment: Can you change server.py so it'll dump funcs to a file that test.py can access?

Comment: I believe I can if that change only affects the register function. I have a giant batch of unit tests that I must respect.

Comment: Got it- and what info do you need from funcs? I'm guessing the name (e.g. `hello`) and the function name?

Comment: That's actually the worst part... i need the function object itself. Because I'll need to run inspect on that function to retrieve the parameters names that function needs too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212976/discussion-between-maor10-and-walkman).

Comment: Wrote this in the chat- solution seems to me as follows- right before you run server.start, do ```with open('/pasten/whatever.pickle', 'wb') as f: pickle.dump(funcs, f)```
then do ```with open('/pasten/whatever.pickle', 'rb') as f: funcs = pickle.load(f)``` in your test.py file

Answer (score 1):

1. When you directly run server.py, it prints populated func as `__name__=="__main__"` evaluates to true. This doesn't work when server.py is imported in another module though.
2. Also, as a good practice you should add a function to server.py to fetch the `funcs` instead of relying on global.
3. Also, you can refactor the logic inside **name**==**main** to a function  (eg. start_server) so that any module can start the server by just calling this function.

Comment: server.py is the first thing to run and keeps running "infinitely". I can't change how the main works. I can only change where the functions get registered to so that i makes possible to call another module that will know whats inside funcs at all times